# MQTT publish based on a received message

Tags: python, mqtt, paho

Can someone help me? I am beginner into this, I am trying to build a script with `paho-mqtt` to publish something if I receive a value from another VM.

For example, if the first VM publish "hello", I want to reply it with "hi" with the second VM in the same channel.

I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

server = "192.168.200.221"
client = mqtt.Client("VM2")
client.connect(server)
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        if str(msg.payload) == "Hello":
                client.publish("test", "HI")
                time.sleep(5)
                print("It works")
while True:
        client.on_message = on_message
```

Comment: why the `time.sleep(5)`-call? - also, you don't need to do this in a loop `client.on_message = on_message`, once suffices. Call `client.loop()` in the `while`-loop instead. See this tutorial for instance: http://www.steves-internet-guide.com/into-mqtt-python-client/

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to start the client's [network loop](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#network-loop) to have it process incoming messages.

Second, you need to subscribe to a topic for the `on_message` callback to be triggered. This is best done from a `on_connect` callback so it is only done if the connection succeeds.

Third, you should never make blocking calls (e.g. sleep) in the message handler callback as this stops the client from processing any messages (including keep alive pings) until the handler returns.

If you need to add delay then you need to look at starting other threads to do the message processing, but that is much more advanced.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import time

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        client.subscribe('foo')     

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        if msg.payload.decode('utf-8') == "Hello":
                client.publish("test", "HI")
                print("It works")

server = "192.168.200.221"
client = mqtt.Client("VM2")
client.on_message = on_message
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.connect(server)
client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: Ty for your help, but still dont publishing when receiving a msg from the another VM

Comment: Do you get the "It works" message? add more print statements to the `on_message` callback and a `on_connect` callback to see what is happening where.

Comment: Didnt get the message, but i can see in the logs of the server that i am connected to the server, just isnt publishing

Comment: Sorry, just realised there is no call to `client.subscribe()` to tell it what topics to subscribe to. Edited, will now receive all messages sent to topic `foo`

Comment: You also need to use `decode('utf-8)` not `str()`